# Does obfuscating a security model have a place in password security?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, password-protection, salt

When it comes to password security there are things that people agree on like storing salted hashes of passwords, which gives a statistical defense against a compromised model and data.

What some don't seem to agree with are what to do with the salts. There are an infinite number of techniques you can do to try to protect the salts as well, but many experts will suggest that they are just pointless obfuscation of the security model, and that over time the model will be exposed, and I find myself disagreeing with this, but I may not be understanding the other viewpoint.

What I don't understand is if your model is compromised, why should you assume a full compromise instead of a partial? If your security model is distributed across different pieces of infrastructure which aren't equally secured, a partial compromise might not even be a problem. (If you do something like, say, encrypt the salt and retrieve the encryption-key from a more highly secured environment that is less likely to be compromised)

I'm assuming that a compromise isn't always 100% here. I've never had a system hacked nor have I ever hacked so I don't have the complete picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference between obfuscation and encryption is that what is obfuscated can be clarified *without the need for anything beyond the obfuscated information* - as long as you can figure out the type of data you are looking at, then you can find a way to clarify it.

Encryption, meanwhile, can only be decrypted with the right key/password/cracking tool. Encrypted data without those things is very secure.

Consequently obfuscation can at best slow down a determined attacker, although it might put off a less determined one. There are many easier and more maintainable things you can do around the security of your system and your servers to harden them against less determined attackers, so the cost of obfuscation in terms of additional work for you and your systems is rarely justified in my opinion.

To assume a compromise is not 100% when one occurs is a very risky endeavour as what you are actually assuming is that you are smarter and more aware of your system than your attacker. You may be right, but if you *assume* it and you are wrong then you are in very serious trouble indeed. You have to prove it, and given the problems with proving a negative it is safer to act as though you have been compromised completely when a compromise occurs and to design your systems so that they are as secure as possible even in the situation where a total compromise has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

> if your model is compromised, why should you assume a full compromise
>   instead of a partial?

You should always assume the worst case in security. This is the safest approach.

> a partial compromise might not even be a problem

Perhaps. But are you really sure?
In your OP you are basing your analysis on too many assumptions. Perhaps in a very specific setup your evaluation that a partial compromise might not be a problem might be justifiable.
But then again you assume that the attacker is not good enough to find a hole.
Don't base your security model on assumptions.

Comment: You have to make assumptions when you design your Application Security.

Comment: Not in the security aspect.You should not.

Comment: @Thomas if you assume the worst, you will have a more secure application.

Comment: There are Questions you can answer: How much value is a particular System? Who is using / has access to the application? Against which type of attacker we can defend? But sometimes you have to make assumptions. Think about legacy code from another developer or a open-source project. How likely is it that a undiscovered securtiy vulnerability exists. What could be done with it. How likely is it a vulnerability is discovered while I am on vacation? How likely will my sysadmin go crazy? Who will attack the application. Think about governments with access to the datacenter...

Comment: Thanks for replies. I think I didn't state the question correctly. I didn't mean obfuscation instead of security. Build the system assuming 100% compromise and do everything you can to secure it based on those assumptions and best practices. What I mean is, should assuming that 100% environment compromise deter you from going further with it?

Answer (score 0):

Security through obscurity, is, at best, a gamble.  Does it pay to store the salt somewhere else?  Probably.  But you have to look at the cost versus reward when you start getting into these multi-step security setups.  I would say, if your application requires it, you will know it.  Otherwise, adding more steps into the application for the sake of having super intense security may only give yourself headaches when things go wrong.  Not everyone needs NASA level security for their systems.  That isn't to say security isn't important.  It's just that you need to temper it to your current environment.